# Query failed in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE student_id = $child AND school_id = $college";
$result = mysqli_query($conic, $query);
  if(!$result){
      die(" query failed");
      echo 'error here';
  } else {
```

i am trying to retrieve some information from the SQL database but the query seems to fail any ideas?

Comment: The question isn't specific enough, please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Try `die(mysqli_error())` to find out what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must learn more  : how to retrieve data from database using select in php

so try out following example to display all the records from Student table

```
    <?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'rootpassword';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_id = '"$child"' AND school_id = '"$college"' ";

mysql_select_db('test_db');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    // some code here 
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

**NOTE**

> The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future:
>   use **mysqli** or **PDO**

Comment: please, please, *please* use mysqli or PDO. It will not maintain or scale otherwise

Comment: that note is what I was emphasizing to OP